# If/Else Checking header order of entire row

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

I'm trying to run an if/else test that will look at a row of column headers and throw out an error/stop sub if the header row does not match a specific order of header names.

I have a very basic code put together for initial testing which is working, however, it is looking at each individual column header name so I'm getting a long list of message box notifications.

I know there is a way that I could just have the macro look at the entire row as a whole and either proceed or stop based on if the row matches or not.  I just can't figure out how/what to manipulate in my code.  Pretty new at this.  Any help would be appreciated!

```
Sub testheaders()

Dim arrCols, x As Long, sht As Worksheet, f As Range, s

'All the fields in the final version in specific order needed
arrCols = Array("Plan Number", "Plan Name", "Division Basis    ", "Division Value    ", "Division Name    ", "SSN", "SSN Ext", "Participant Name", "Hire Date", "Term Date", "LOA Reason", ...........)

Set sht = ActiveSheet


For Each Row In arrCols
    Set f = sht.Rows(1).Find(What:=s, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
    If Not f Is Nothing Then
        'header found
        MsgBox "header found"

    Else
        'not found
        MsgBox "missing header"

    End If

Next s

End Sub
```

Comment: If you don't want to see a message box, then consider removing the statements that produce it.  If you want your macro to `Stop` if the header is not present, then insert a `Stop` statement `if f is nothing`

Comment: Thanks Ron.  I guess having those boxes pop up for testing was more of a problem than it was helping!

Comment: If the sheet contains a `ListObject` (aka "a range formatted as a table"), then there's a *much* neater way to get its header row. Does it?

Comment: I'm not following your code, you have `For Each Row In arrCols` but close it with `Next s`, and then in your `.Find` you have `What:=s`. Are you looking to find each each value from your Array in row 1 ?

Comment: Instead of using `MsgBox` it would be a lot cleaner to just use the `debug.print` function. That way you won't get bombarded with popups.

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below, I went with a different approach, using the `Application.Match` Function.

(You can remove the `MsgBox` if you want)

```
Sub testheaders()

Dim arrCols, sht As Worksheet, s
Dim LastCol As Long, HeaderRng As Range


'All the fields in the final version in specific order needed
arrCols = Array("Plan Number", "Plan Name", "Division Basis    ", "Division Value    ", "Division Name    ", "SSN", "SSN Ext", "Participant Name", "Hire Date", "Term Date", "LOA Reason")

Set sht = ActiveSheet

With sht
    ' find last column with data in the first row
    LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    ' set the scanned range with data in the Header row
    Set HeaderRng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, LastCol))

    For Each s In arrCols
        If IsError(Application.Match(s, HeaderRng, 0)) Then '<-- no Match
            MsgBox s & " is a missing header"
        Else '<-- successful match
            MsgBox s & " header found"
        End If        
    Next s
End With

End Sub
```